# Spring Boot UnknownHostException while connecting to RDS throgh VPC peering

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I am getting the **UnknownHostException** while trying to deploy a **Spring Boot** application to a **K8s Cluster** in **AWS EKS**.

Scenario:

- I have a AWS EKS Cluster running on a VPC (A) and the RDS is running on a VPC (B).
- I have created the VPC peering connection between the two VPCs, enabling DNS resolution and configuring the routing tables accordingly.
- I also created a K8s Service mapping the external RDS endpoint.

If I try to connect to the RDS instance from **EKS Cluster** using a busybox like this:

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
```

with any of the following options, **it works**:

```
/ # nc mysql-service 3306

/ # nc mysql-service.default.svc.cluster.local 3306

/ # nc xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
```

But when I deploy my Spring Boot application it doesn't work.

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54)
at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93)
at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133)
at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:83)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:144)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1676)
... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-service
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I am trying out same and I am facing same error   , I have added RDS as external service in yaml. Though busybox based verification doesnt work for me when I do same from different nginx pod it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The whole VPC Peering configuration is working. The K8s external service is also working. The problem was in my Spring Boot application.

I had configured the data source URL with an environment variable which was causing the error. For some reason, Spring doesn't resolve the host configured with an environment variable.

I just changed the spring configuration from:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:3306/db_name
```

to:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:3306/db_name
```

and now it works!

Comment: it seems weird to me, as in your question, there error Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-service implied env variable got resolved.

Comment: @sayboras, that's exactly what I thought. I just did another test and the error persists. The env var is resolved but it throws the exception. If I hardcode it the error disappears. Very weird indeed.

Comment: Which EKS version you are using?